# Should I accept an edit that replaces a broken link with a link that the editor considers "helpful"?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, broken-link

I encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30393429) suggested edit, where the editor replaced a link that is now dead with the link that helped the editor.

I skipped the edit because I don't know what to do.

What should my action be?

Comment: I would accept an archived link. But if it is a completely different URL, then it might not be what the OP wants. But that's just me.

Comment: I'm just here to say well done for correctly using the skip button when you don't know what to do.

Comment: I think it's better to replace it with [this link](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/examples/4-simple-ways-to-call-a-graphql-api/). This article has the same title and is on the same website.

Comment: briken links are bad and should be replaced. @Miscellaneous link is defacto better, but the offered link was also okay it explains in detail the wanted information. ifrist guest it was spam, because you have to go down to find the nformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This likely doesn't cover all cases but this is what I generally do for link edits:

- **Check that the original link is actually broken.**
  This doesn't happen a lot but sometimes spammers will change a perfectly good link to an official source to one that links to their web site.
- **Check that the new link isn't spam.**
  Sometimes you can tell something is spam by looking at the URL but sometimes you'll have to follow the link to be sure.
- **If the original link was quoted, make sure the new URL also contains the quote.**
  If it doesn't, it's probably wrong or at least not what the OP intended.
- **In absence of a quote, make sure the new URL is about what the answer says it is about.**
  This includes the specificity of the page and versioning. For example, let's say there's a question about modals in Bootstrap version 3.4 and it has an answer that includes a link to the official documentation for modals in 3.4.
  An edit that changed the link to just point to the top level of the documentation would be bad because the author's intent was to point users to the modal documentation.
  An edit that changed the link to point to the latest version of the documentation would also be bad because then there would be a mismatch between what the answer says to do and what the linked documentation says to do.
- **Check that the link goes someplace trustworthy.** Trustworthy places include (but aren't limited to):

  - The Wayback Machine
  - Official Documentation
  - Links to other Stack Exchange pages (though a link to another Stack Overflow answer could be an indication the question is a duplicate)
  - Links to sites that are listed as resources in the tags (I can't promise all links in all tags are good but normally these go to trusted sites)

Comment: If the link is not useful for anything, feel free to just remove it.